# How to call Console Application functions in Web forms in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, api, console-application

I have a solution that contains two projects the web application project and console application.

I call web API in the console application (in Program.cs class) and store the output in a list, and I want to display the list in my web form in the web application project. How can I call the function from Program.cs to my webform to display the result?

or if there is an easiest solution instead of this?

Comment: Create a new API which gives you the same data. Consume that API in your web project. You can save the data in any database or file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the following steps to call console app functions in web forms.

First, please define the program.cs in your console app.

```
namespace TestConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        public static List<string> Liststring()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("test1");
            list.Add("test2");
            list.Add("test3");
            list.Add("test4");
            return list;

        }
    }
}
```

Second, In the web app, please click add-reference ->Projects-> Choose the console app.

Third, Please add the using statement in the top of the code.

Finally, you can use the following code to fill a list in the dropdownlist.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using TestConsole;


namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Dropdownlist1.DataSource = Program.Liststring();
                Dropdownlist1.DataBind();
            }
      

        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the Web API is you're calling from console application is an external one (not part of your web application).

I would have separated the logic reading from the Web API in a separate project and used that from both the console and web application.